# Combining SUMIFS or SUMIF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

this is my data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PX7-RxYJGi74bwUZ8Y2QzJEkKDIdTRL6yjQvWYcUxm0/edit#gid=959894984

```
A       B       C           D       E                F           G
date    item    warehouse   qty     last checked                 a
1       a       x           1       4                            b
4       a       x           5       4 
8       a       x           10      4 
5       a       x           7       4 
7       a       y           2       5 
5       a       y           3       5 
5       b       x           1       5 
6       b       y           2       6 
7       b       x           4       6 
8       b       y           5       6
```

i want to do a calculation as below:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"x",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,("b"=B:B)*("x"=C:C),0))) + SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"y",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,("b"=B:B)*("y"=C:C),0)))
```

is there any way for me to make it like this:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"x",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(("a" or "b"=B:B)*("x"=C:C),0)))
```

or

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"x",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,({a,b}=B:B)*("x"=C:C),0)))
```

or given that "a" and "b" is located in G:G

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"x",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(g:g=B:B)*("x"=C:C),0)))
```

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PX7-RxYJGi74bwUZ8Y2QzJEkKDIdTRL6yjQvWYcUxm0/edit?usp=sharing this is the updated link, thankyou!!

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

valid way of doing this `("a" or "b"=B:B)*("x"=C:C)` would be:

```
(("a"=B:B)+("b"=B:B))*("x"=C:C)
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"b",C:C,"x",A:A,">"&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(("a"=B:B)+("b"=B:B))*("x"=C:C),0)))
```

[image: 0]